# Body undefined in fetch, http

Tags: http, fetch

In body server write some text : "This is text from server".
I try read response.body, but response.body is undefined

```
fetch('https://somesite.com/restapi/session', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include'
    }).then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                let username = response.body;
                ....
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same problem. Were you able to find a solution for it ?

Comment: @PratikSinghal do you still need a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi @NEO, Figured out the solution to this problem.

Comment: @PratikSinghal perfectly)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering this, in case anyone else faces this problem.

fetch API provides two methods `.json()` and `.text()` which return a promise which resolves to the result returned by API call.

Comment: But this doesn't answer what to do if we want `body`, which is a ReadableStream and are working with something that uses the streaming interface

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually looking for `.body`, which is a `ReadableStream`, it should be there. `cross-fetch` (a very popular npm package) does not current implement this, so you may run into it from there.

https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch/issues/121